# Ссылка на объект в js

Tags: javascript

Есть объект

```
var App = {
    id : '-1',
    app:function (url){
            post('http://...'+getCookie('token'),url,function (res){
            data = JSON.parse(res)['data'];
            Здесь нужен доступ к id
        });
    },
    view:function (){
        //alert(this.id);
        //this.view_app_info();
    }
};
```

Как внутри Callback функции получить доступ к свойству id.